# pygame fails in relocating images

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have a list of images to be located to the center of the screen.

```
def relocate_images(self, images):
    for image in images:
        print('the center is ' + str(image.get_rect().center))
        x_diff = int(self.width/2) - image.get_rect().x #self.width is the width of the screen
        y_diff = int(self.height/2) - image.get_rect().y #self.height is the height of the screen
        image.get_rect().move(x_diff, y_diff)
        print('the center is ' + str(image.get_rect().center))
```

The centers displayed on the screen are the same. So the value didn't signed to the image?

Answer (score 0):

An image doesn't have a position. The method `image.get_rect()` returns a rectangle the size of the image, but always at position (0, 0). You yourself have to create and manage all positions of all images. I would suggest creating a list of rectangles which you would pass into the method, and also use the same list of rectangles for blitting. Alternatively, create a class that contains the image and it's corresponding rectangle.